# Relating Path Partials to Partial of the Function Along the Path PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

On Evans PDE, page 97 this outlines the process of finding the characteristic ODE. Given a function $F(Du,u,x) = 0$ where $F \in \mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ on some open set, where $Du$ has dimension $n$, $u$ is scalar valued, and $x$ also has dimension $n$.

Define a parametric path by $x(s)$, and then $z(s) = u(x(s))$ so $z$ scalar valued. Similarly, define $p(s) = Du(s)$ with $p(s) = (p_1(s), \dots, p_n(s)$. This allows us to rewrite the function $F(Du, u, x)$ as $F(p(s), z(s), x(s))$. My question is how (8), the relation $\frac{d}{ds}x_j(s) = F_{p_j}(p(s),z(s),x(s))$, comes about.

I see how equations (6) and (7) are derived, ie relation $\frac{d}{ds} p_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} u_{x_i x_j}(x(s))x_j(s)$ (where $u_{x_ix_j}$ is the second order partial) and $\sum_{j=1}^n F_{p_j}(p(s),z(s),x(s))u_{x_ix_j} + F_z(p(s),z(s),x(s))u_{x_i} + F_{x_i}(p(s),z(s),x(s))$ come from but am confused about the step outlined above.